# Grails, editable value in <g:select>

Tags: select, grails, view

I want to give the users an opportunity to type in their own text if not in the list. This text should not be added to the list but it should be the value sent when the form is submitted.
I have the feeling that this is not possible with the  but what other solutions exist? This is common in windows applications at least.

Comment: Maybe just show a text input under your drop down with appropriate text guidance

Comment: I've thought about that, the easiest but not the nicest. I think I go for that but if someone has a more elegant you're always welcome to share it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

gsp:

```
<label>Choose an colour:
<input list="colours" name="aColour" /></label>
    <datalist id="colours">
        <option value="Red">
        <option value="Blue">
        <option value="White">
    </datalist>
```

controller:

```
params.aColour
```